# How to use the URL for my Map Service in ArcGIS Server Manager?

Tags: model-view-controller, dictionary, arcgis, arcgis-server

I am having a Map Service from a ArcGIS Server Manager which I would like to add to the .cshtml page of my MVC project is this possible like the way shown in here by ESRI

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/index.html#latest_samples

I am able to use the samples but how do I use my Map.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ArcGIS API for JavaScript** or **.NET Web Application Developer Framework (.NET Web ADF)** for MVC project.

For getting started see [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgisserver/web-apis), [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/) and [this](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/serveradf_net/adf_home.html).